# HDD is shown in Ubuntu, but isn't in Windows

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

Windows 11 double boot via Grub with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I had bought new HDD, but it wasn't showing in Windows at all. Not in disk maganger, nor in any third-party software, yet was perfectly fine on Ubuntu. So I went to google the issue. Apparently, the disk was wrong format, so using Ubuntu disk tool I've formatted it into NTFS, yet no success. I thought it could've been Ubuntu's tool incapability and wanted to use external Ubuntu tools, but haven't found anything, all roads led to "Rome", Ubuntu's Disk Utility. Using Windows software via Wine was of no use, I could've not attach the disk to Wine for some reasons, it just wasn't showing as well (I've used /media/Username/DiskUUID format, as /dev/sda1 wasn't even a path for the Wine).

Any tips?

Edit:
I've tried to disconnect and reconnect HDD, nothing changed.
[Disk C: 2 partitions for Windows, 100GB for Ubuntu, none Disk D.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orjem.png)

Comment: I suggest to replace the disk.

Comment: @harrymc Bold. Effective. But I'm not ready to give up yet, I was searching this disk way too long, and luckily got the very last item of kind in the store. Ah, also, the model is Western Digital WD Blue 2TB SATA 6Gb/s HDD Desktop

Comment: Windows only supports NTFS or exFAT? So what file system were you using before you attempted to switch to NTFS?

Comment: @Ramhound I am very sorry, but I cannot answer which file system was there before, as it is already few days since I've begun trying and in my first attempt I didn't bothered to write that down, as I thought it was just a minor issue.

Comment: So the disk is not showing up in File Explorer what about Disk Management?

Comment: @Ramhound as said in post, no luck neither in File Explorer, nor Disk Manager, nor any third-party software. I'm thinking about reconnecting disk power supply or re-plug SATA to look what happens.

Comment: To be clear: Unless formatted with a file system Windows recognizes it WON'T show up in file manager so saying "none Disk D" is nonsensical. But it SHOULD appear in disk management with unidentified partition(s) otherwise. So, 2 questions: 1. How is the drive mode set in UEFI ("BIOS")? 2. How does it show up in Ubuntu? Related: what exactly happened when you tried to format in Ubuntu and how exactly did you go about it?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Answer to the second question: Everything went completely fine, chose NTFS and pressed format. 8 Hours later job is done and just like that it is appearing in Ubuntu Disk Utility, like NTFS disk and everything is ok. About the first question, I'm going to answer it in a minite.

Comment: If the disk is not listed in Disk Management then the disk is not functional, based on your description, neither Linux (WINE) nor Windows detects the drive.

Comment: @ChanganAuto You helped me solve the issue. During PC building I was in despair trying to make NVMe SSD to be recognized and set SATA Mode to RAID. Changed it to AHCI, solved the issue. Answer the question and I'll pin you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments, the problem stemmed from setting a "RAID" mode in UEFI that required additional software in Windows to manage it and resulted in the drive not being recognized (in Windows).

Ubuntu somehow could handle the drive independently.

Settings the drive mode to **AHCI** solved the issue.